# Google Maps Events

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map in my project with multiple marks. My objective is when I click in the mark, this execute a function (toggleBounce). So I add each marker to a google.maps.event.addListener, like this:

```
for(var i in markers){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', toggleBounce);
}
```

And work well! So my problem is in the function toggleBounce, how I can pass the number of the marker ?

```
function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker[WHAT I NEED TO PUT HERE?].getAnimation() != null) {
    marker[WHAT I NEED TO PUT HERE?].setAnimation(null);
  } 
  else {
    marker[WHAT I NEED TO PUT HERE?].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `this` in the event handler event (it is the marker):

```
function toggleBounce() {
  if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
    this.setAnimation(null);
  } 
  else {
    this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/L6n54xds/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function toggleBounce() {
  if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
    this.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunker which might help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4hFdmxji9C74ymBL1qtS?p=preview

```
var createMarker = function (info){                   

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.lon),
                    title: info.place
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
                    //do your stuff
                if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
                } 
               else {
               marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
               }
             });                    
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                items[i].id=i+'AM@_255';
                createMarker(items[i]);
            }
```